# Android Canvas not updated or invalidate

Tags: android, canvas

I have newgame .txt file in my asset folder. I read this file in character array (cboard) in `loadboard()` method. Then on the basis of values in `cboard` array i fill `Pboard` array (Pieces array, logical array) and bmp array (bitmap array, physical board) in `fillboard()`. i have another function `populate()` which draw bitmap images on canvas. I have `updateBoard()` where I have updated both physical array (bmp) and logical array (`Pboard`). after calling `updateBoard()` my logical array `Pboard` and physical array `bmp` is updated but when i draw it on canvas it has the old configuration. Here are my calls to `loadboard(),fillboard(),populate` function.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width=View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height=View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);`
        b=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        c=new Canvas(b);

       loadboard();
           fillBoard();
       calculateLinePlacement();
       drawBoard();
           // method draw the board and bitmap images ( call populate()).


    }
```

after `updateBoard()` function i call `invalidate()`;

EDIT1:

Following is the `updateBoard()` method (copied from commnet):

```
public void updateBoard(int sr, int sc, int er, int ec) {
Pboard[sr][sc] = new Empty(sr, sc, -3, "empty", board);
Pboard[er][ec] = selectedp;
Bitmap img = bmp[sr][sc];
bmp[sr][sc] = null;
bmp[er][ec] = null;
bmp[er][ec] = img;
}
```

Comment: from where are you calling the `updateBoard()` method?

Comment: @ Praful Bhatnagar.. i call updateBoard() in ontouchevent and after that this.invalidate()... both my bitmap array (bmp) and piece array (Pboard) is updated but not drawn on canvas..

Comment: try with postInvalidate()...

Comment: i already tried PostInvalidate()...

Comment: can you show some more code... `onDraw()` and the `updateBoard()` method..

Comment: let me know when i call invalidate or postinvalidate so onMeasure function is called every time or not... because i want to run loadboard() and fillboard() only once for first time when game start, not after every move. any idea?

Comment: Assuming you are creating a custom view.. then you would have to write your rendering code in `onDraw()` method.. to change anything just change the state on the view and call `invalidate()/posInvalidate()` this would make system to call `onDraw()` again... and you need to use the current view state to render the view in the `onDraw()` method..

Comment: @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //super.onDraw(canvas);
  c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
  setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
 }

Comment: is this a custom view? are you rendering the view in the `onDraw()`? what is the purpose of `drawBoard()` method? please see my previous comment...

Comment: public void updateBoard(int sr,int sc,int er,int ec)
   {
    Pboard[sr][sc]=new Empty(sr, sc, -3, "empty", board);
    Pboard[er][ec]=selectedp;
  
  
  Bitmap img=bmp[sr][sc];
  bmp[sr][sc]=null;
  bmp[er][ec]=null;
  bmp[er][ec]=img;
  
  
    
   }

Comment: @praful  drawBoard() method draw lines on the canvas and then call populate() method to place images on specified position. i just want draw images on canvas after every piece move, mean every time after updateboard() method is called....

Comment: please answer the question I asked in my previous comment.. if this is a custom view... then you can only use `onDraw()` for rendering...